# Integer as object_identifier in Logtalk

Tags: object, integer, identifier, logtalk

I have a protocol students:

```
:- protocol(student).
    :- public([
        name/1,
        surname/1,
        studies/1,
        marks/1
    ]).
:- end_protocol.
```

Now I want to make an object which name is an ID (Integer), but when I'm trying to do this with `create_object(18342, [implements(student)], [], [name(john), surname(smith), studies(it), marks(ok)]).`

swilgt gives mi the error:

> ERROR: Type error: 'object_identifier' expected, found '18342' (an integer)

Ofc I could use quotation marks, but I don't want to. 
Is there an option to use integer as a name, or have I use string and add id/1 into the protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed is (currently) not possible to use an integer as an object identifier. One alternative is indeed to use an atom, e.g. `'133'` instead of `123`. Don't use a string, e.g. `"123"` as the actual meaning of double quoted text depends on the `double_quotes` standard Prolog flag, whose only portable value is `codes`(i.e. `"123"` is parsed as `[49,50,51]`.

A portable way to convert between an integer and an atom is to use the standard predicates `number_codes/2` and `atom_codes/2` (or `number_chars/2` and `atom_chars/2`). Some supported backend Prolog systems also provide proprietary built-in predicates to directly convert between numbers and atoms.